# Access android system progress dialogue image

Tags: android

I want to use the android system image that is used for the purpose of displaying the progress bar.

For example the progress bar with the following code:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

displays this image [image: The android system image]

I want to set this image inside an ImageView programatically. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: you want to show progressbar while image is loading ??

Comment: Yes, i want to do that I can do that using AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> extension but at the same time i do not want any external dependency. The point is i want to make this class reusable. Such that it have in itself the way to display a progress while the image is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can find native res in $ANDROID_SDK/platforms/android-21/data/res/
This image is called spinner_16_outer_holo or spinner_16_inner_holo. '16' is dimensions. There are other dimensions too.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But how to do that programatically. I do not want to add this file inside my current project resources.

Answer (score 0):

Create a raw file layout like this.. and set image to `ImageView` after it downloaded. So progressbar hides automatically.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/imageframe"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@color/white">

     <ProgressBar
         android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
         style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center" />

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageOverlay"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:scaleType="centerInside"
         android:contentDescription="@string/blank"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

PS : Set hight and width as per your need..